# Issues with async event handling in Android widgets

Tags: android, asynchronous, spinner

I have a Spinner and EditText widgets in a form. The `onItemSelected` for the Spinner sets the text for the EditText with the selected item value..

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        EditText txt2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt2);
        System.out.println("Setting from onItemSelected");
        txt2.setText(((TextView)view).getText().toString());
    }
});
spinner.setSelection(sel);
spinner.setEnabled(false);
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt2);
System.out.println("Setting from outside onItemSelected");
et.setText("Testing");
```

But the last statement in the above code has no effect because `setText()` from inside the `onItemSelected` is called after it. I know this can happen due to the asynchrony, but is there a way to have control over it to force intended sequence of calling setText()?

Comment: What's the solution in 2022?

Answer (score 0):

Probably several better solutions, but a quick fix would be to do this:

```
    new Thread(){
       public void run(){
         try{
           Thread.sleep(1000);
         } catch(Exception e){}
           et.setText("Testing");
       }
     }.run();
```

Would need to set et to be final, and also ensure that you are running `et.setText()` on the UI thread with:

```
runOnUiThread( new Runnable(){
   public void run(){
     et.setText("Testing");
   }
});
```

That should do the trick.